# How to detect all hard drives on a machine using PHP

Tags: php, drive

How can PHP be used to detect all drives on a computer? This detection would include:

- Hard disks
- Pen drives
- Hard drives

And how can this be done across multiple platforms, such as Linux and Windows?

Comment: This really isn't a php issue. Go research how you can get what you need from command line, then use one of PHP's exec functions to make the call.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Linux, you can use PHP's `exec()` function to execute the following 2 commands:

```
fdisk -l
```

which list out the disk & partition as follow:

```
Disk /dev/xvda1: 10.7 GB, 10737418240 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1305 cylinders, total 20971520 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/xvda1 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/xvda2: 365.0 GB, 365041287168 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 44380 cylinders, total 712971264 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/xvda2 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/xvda3: 939 MB, 939524096 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 114 cylinders, total 1835008 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/xvda3 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

and this command:

```
mount
```

which list out active mount points, including swap. Output as follow:

```
/dev/xvda1 on / type ext4 (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
/dev/xvda2 on /mnt type ext3 (rw)
```

By parsing the output of these, you can obtain all drives' information. There are more commands (e.g. `cat /proc/partitions`) available in Linux, you can explore for alternatives.

---

For Windows, it's more complicated. You can use (required Administrative privileges):

```
fsutil fsinfo drives
```

which returns (not very informative):

```
Drives: C:\ D:\ E:\ F:\
```

Detailed drive information can be obtained via:

```
diskpart
```

then issue:

```
list volume
```

then the following output will be shown:

```
Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
Volume 0     E                       DVD-ROM         0 B  No Media
Volume 1         System Rese  NTFS   Partition    100 MB  Healthy    System
Volume 2     C   System       NTFS   Partition     99 GB  Healthy    Boot
Volume 3     F   Data (local  NTFS   Partition    365 GB  Healthy
```

But since PHP is unable to execute the command and type more than 1 command to the input, you probably cannot obtain the information directly. Consider using a batch program to output the required information and use PHP to call that batch program.

Comment: just a little question can are php `exec()` statements safe, do they execute arbitrary code without checking it

Comment: `exec()` did not check whether the commands / statements are safe. Therefore, use it carefully.